# concatenating staggered columns

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I am working on a macro to loop through staggered columns of strings and concatenate them. Basically data gets added into the columns over time so I need to make it "future-proof". At the moment it picks up all of column H and I but only the first value of J and K. Not sure why it works for half but not the other. I am thinking its to do with my .End(xldown) as i am used to using rows.end(xlup).count to loop through things, but never when it is part of the range?
Here is my code:

```
Sub Concatenation_for_the_nation()

Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
For i = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("H" & i).Select
    StrStrONE = StrStrONE & " " & Selection
Next i
Cells(1, 1).Select

Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select
For j = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("I" & j).Select
    StrStrTWO = StrStrTWO & " " & Selection
Next j
Cells(1, 1).Select

Range("J2").End(xlDown).Select
For k = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("J" & k).Select
    StrStrTHREE = StrStrTHREE & " " & Selection
Next k
Cells(1, 1).Select

Range("K2").End(xlDown).Select
For l = 1 To ActiveCell.Row
    Range("K" & l).Select
    StrStrFOUR = StrStrFOUR & " " & Selection
Next l
Cells(1, 1).Select

Cells(21, 21) = StrStrONE & StrStrTWO & StrStrTHREE & StrStrFOUR

Cells(20, 20) = "Jeff"

MsgBox "steve the pirate"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ron De Bruin's website addresses this http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: tried Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End (xlUp) but doesn't work. I can see sort of how to put it in its own sub. but struggling to see how to fit it into a one liner at the beginning of the for next loop? sorry am pretty new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating the same logic multiple times, so it makes sense to pull it out into a separate Sub.

Tested:

```
Sub Concatenation_for_the_nation()

    Dim c As Range, s As String, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For Each c In sht.Range("H1:K1")
        s = s & ColumnString(c)
    Next c

    sht.Cells(21, 21).Value = s
    sht.Cells(20, 20).Value = "Jeff"

    MsgBox "arrrrr"

End Sub


Function ColumnString(cStart As Range, Optional sep As String = " ")
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rv As String
    Set rng = cStart.Parent.Range(cStart, _
                     cStart.Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, cStart.Column).End(xlUp))
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        rv = rv & sep & c.Value
    Next c
    ColumnString = rv
End Function
```